# close modal on button click

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, angular-datatables

we are developing cms for a website in that i have listed all post in datatable i want to delete that post when user will click on delete button

i have called my service on that button row gets deleted from database but on frontend its not loading lattes result and my modal is not closing 
please see below images,
[image]
when i click on delete button modal appears

[image]

when i click on yes,delete button i have called service that deletes row from database its working fine, what i am facing is modal is not getting closed and that table is not reloading its data,

i want to know is there any way to refresh specific components in angular 5? 
or how can i deal with this

please let me know if you want any inputs from my side,

please give me your valuable suggestions

**all things are working now i am having just a little problem that my modal is not closing on button click**

following i my code

```
 <div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

        <!-- ID Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="post_title">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Post Title </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.post_title}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
<!-- 
        <ng-container matColumnDef="post_description">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Post Description </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [innerHTML]="row.post_description"></mat-cell>
        </ng-container> -->

        <!-- Progress Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="category_title">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Post Category </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.category_title}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Post Status </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.status}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Color Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Post Location </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.location}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="buttons">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <button mat-button [routerLink]="['../update-post/',row.post_id]">
                    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                </button>
                 <button mat-button (click)="open(content)">
                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
                          <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <p>Are you sure you want to delete the post?</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark"  data-dismiss="modal"  (click)="deletePost(row.post_id)">Yes, Delete</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">No</button>
                        </div>
                      </ng-template>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
        </mat-row>
    </mat-table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Comment: it will work in angular?

Comment: when i gave call to the nginit its now working but just one little problem is modal is not closing

Comment: cal u please help me with that

Comment: Lets start over.... How are you displaying your modal ? Toggling a class, `*ngIf`?

Comment: please see my code

Comment: Do you handle close modal? It will not close automatically.

Comment: try `<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="close('Close click')">No</button>`

Comment: yup its worked same way post this as answer

Answer (score 0):

in the button event click when we call the service of delete record 
after successful deletion in success block you write below code to hide your model popup..

$('#myModal').modal('show');   //#myModal is id of your model

and after that call the method which are  bind your grid 
i hope it will be work for you

Comment: i am writing it in angular